# What analogies are there for thinking about the flow of time?

Tags: time, metaphilosophy

What analogies are there for thinking about the flow of time? **Assuming** that time has the following characteristics:

1. Only the present exists (not the past and future)
2. The present is a fiction
3. The future contains the past
4. The flow of time is irreversible.

I simply do not have the cognitive skill necessary to fully imagine such a scenario. Obviously philosophers have deployed metaphors to describe time, before:

- Heraclitus' super famous use of '***river*** of time'
- I believe the physicist Eddington's '[***arrow*** of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_of_time)'

But the first falls foul of 1 (the whole goddamn mississippi exists), and the second 2 (arrows have real effects).

Comment: if a bad question, likely **cannot** be improved. so just leave a comment and i'll erase, please :)

Comment: Some of your options are close to the standard metaphysical theories of time, [eternalism, presentism, and growing block](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/time/#PreEteGroUniThe), another option is that time is an illusion. They invoke various metaphors, but above all try to articulate coherent doctrines that explain our intuitions of time.

Comment: @Conifold somewhat helpful thanks. Looks like presentism, fictionalism, time's arrow... the 3rd claim defeats me (and google). One could maybe think of this as a single non real atom (for obvious reasons), but I've no idea how to define its movement, given times don't repeat. Any ideas, I shouldn't ask on mathematics.s. A line in a specific kind of space?

Comment: @Conifold if you're interested, seems like we're talking about a point the line of which is arbitrarily in euclidean and non euclidean space. In conclusion, I'd need to unpack the third claim, I think into time repeating but not in actuality, or vice versa. Cheers

Comment: The past containing the future is one way to state hard determinism. But future containing the past? I suppose by analogy it should be something like "final destination" shaping how we approach it today, like [Chardin's Omega Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_Point). I am afraid I do not follow the "line in euclidean and non euclidean space" part. Topology of a "line" ([1-manifold](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/1-manifolds)) can only be interval/segment/ray or circle, which space it is in is irrelevant.

Comment: @Conifold what do you mean "not follow"? Philosophers just do use the term "arbitrarily". I don't follow how the phrase could confuse anyone, besides that

Comment: i can't tell if i should delete the question?

Comment: Time flies like an arrow. Fruit flies like a banana.

Comment: "What then is time? If no one asks me, I know what it is. If I wish to explain it to him who asks, I do not know.”
– Saint Augustine

Comment: It is gobbledegook to posit that "only the present exists" but "the present is a fiction".  You may as welll assume that 2 + 2 = 5.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming time has the following characteristics? I don't really agree with any of the characteristics there. What does it mean to say the present is fictional?

To me those characteristics are fairly characteristic of metaphysical assertions which transgress the boundaries of sense.

I think the river analogy is the most common one. Wittgenstein had some great things to say in his Blue and Brown books about how the analogies people make with time cause a lot of the philosophical muddles people get into. When people see an analogy, they tend to ask questions that don't make sense. E.g. there is a certain analogy between time and a river. That is all well and good, but it runs into problems when people carry the analogy too far (like Augustine did with his puzzlement about time).

If one imagines a log flowing down a river, while we stand on the bank, we can imagine saying the log is now downstream, now in front of us, now upstream. That kind of analogy is used to describe events in time. One can ask meaningfully "the log has gone away, I wonder where it is now". But to carry this idea over into the analogy with time is the misstep in thinking. It causes one to ask questions like " oh, I wonder where the past has gone, and whether it exists"